Adding multiple azure function apps in one backend pool in azure application gateway
Requirement
We want that once the request hits the application gateway public IP then as per the path(/abc/*) it should reach out to the particular backend pool but the catch is, that this backend pool has multiple "Azure Function Apps". Lets say function app1, function app2 and function app3. Now how can i make sure that once the request hits the backend pool then it should reach to one function app lets say function app 3.

You should be able to define URL path-based routing rules such that you can realize routing of requests to a specific Azure Function App based on the URL path when using an Azure Application Gateway. Here is how you can do the same.
Configure Backend Pools:
Select the created Application Gateway from list of resources.
Click on "Backend pools".
Add a new backend pool for each of your function apps. For instance, add a backend pool named functionApp3Pool and in to this backend pool, add the particular instance of function app (function app3).
Define HTTP Settings:
In the "HTTP settings" section of the Application Gateway, set up any HTTP setting that corresponds to the back-end pool of function app3. Remember to put in the settings compatible with that—port, protocol, and maybe custom probes if so.
Configure Listeners:
Create a listener to handle incoming traffic For that, go to the "Listeners" section and add a new listener associated with your Application Gateway. The listener is listening on the appropriate port. In general, the port is 80 for HTTP or 443 for the HTTPS version.
Path-based routing rules
Create a new rule
Select the Rule type as "Path-based"
In path Patterns define your path pattern, e.g. /abc/*.
Associate this path pattern with the backend pool of function app3 (e.g., functionApp3Pool).

first of all thanks for your reply, from your answer it seems you are considering a scenario of building one backend pool for one function app. Or you are considering a scenario of multiple functions app in one backend pool as i have asked in my question. Please suggest.
